# running function when selecting shapekeys

Tags: python, interface, shape-keys, properties

I'm trying to run a function (setting the active shapekey value to 1, and all other shapekeys values to 0) when selecting a shapekey.

Not quite sure how to achieve that. I tried subscribing to msgbus but I'm doing something wrong.

```
import bpy

def set_active_shape_key(scene, prop):
    obj = scene.objects.active
    active_shape_key_index = obj.active_shape_key_index
    for shape_key in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
        if shape_key.name != 'Basis':
            shape_key.value = int(shape_key.name == obj.active_shape_key.name)
            print(f'{shape_key.name} set to {shape_key.value}')

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key="object.active_shape_key_index",
    owner=None,
    args=(bpy.context.scene,),
    notify=set_active_shape_key
)
```

posting the a complete solution in case anyone is looking for this -

```
import bpy

owner = None
subscribe_to = (bpy.types.Object, "active_shape_key_index")
#subscribe_to = bpy.context.object.path_resolve("active_shape_key_index", False)


def set_active_shape_key(*args):
    obj = bpy.context.object
    active_shape_key_index = obj.active_shape_key_index
    print(f'{obj.name} shape key index change {active_shape_key_index}')
    for shape_key in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
        if shape_key.name != 'Basis':
            shape_key.value = int(shape_key.name == obj.active_shape_key.name)
            print(f'{shape_key.name} set to {shape_key.value}')


def sub_msg_bus():
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=owner,
        args=(1, 2, 3),
        notify=set_active_shape_key
    )


def clr_msg_bus():
    bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(owner)

classes = []


def upd_mbus_cb(self, context):
    print(f'msg_bus bool: {self.mbus}')
    if context.window_manager.mbus:
        sub_msg_bus()
    else:
        clr_msg_bus()
    return None


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.mbus = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="mbus",
        description="Toggle message bus subscription",
        default=False,
        update=upd_mbus_cb,
        )


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.mbus


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Your `owner` is `None`. Since `None` is a unique value (thanks to that identity comparison `is None` works), I think this technique won't work (properly) for more than one msgbus subscription. This is why Blender docs suggest `owner = object()` instead. Thank you for sharing the answer. 

Comment: If you have a solution you should post it as an answer instead of updating the question with it. That's the accepted way to do it on Stack Exchange. Especially if you want it to be useful to others. People who are used to Stack Exchange format might skip reading the full question and look for a solution below.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the pointers guys. Both in regards to the owner assignment as well as the Stack Exchange format. I need to read more docs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on an [answer I got on Blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/running-function-when-selecting-shapekeys/1445295/3) -

[Message Bus (bpy.msgbus) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html#module-bpy.msgbus)

Some properties are converted to Python objects when you retrieve them. This needs to be avoided in order to create the subscription, by using:

```
datablock.path_resolve("property_name", False)
key = bpy.context.object.path_resolve("active_shape_key_index", False)
```